# Android create chooser shows after long delay

Tags: android, android-intent

When I press button which executes below code chooser pops up after quite long delay like 4s. How can I make that it would be instant because I saw app who has instant chooser.

```
val share = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setSubject(resources.getString(R.string.share_content_title))
            .setText(resources.getString(R.string.share_content))
            .intent
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via"))
```

Comment: That should happen fairly quickly. Are you sure that the 4 seconds occurs after the `startActivity()` call? Or is something in your code delaying the `startActivity()` call?

Comment: yea I'm sure because if I change this code to Log it prints it same second when I press it

Comment: If you get rid of the chooser, and you use `startActivity(intent)`, do you still experience the delay, or does something start up immediately?

Comment: after I got rid of Intent.createChooser there is no delay

Comment: The next test would be to split the chooser stuff into a separate line: `val chooser = Intent.createChooser(share, "Share via")` and `startActivity(chooser)`, with logging to see whether it is `Intent.createChooser()` that is slow or if it is starting the chooser activity that is slow. There is very little that you can do about either of those things -- something strange is going on with your test device. But, it is possible that this information will help you decide on possible workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, your code *should* be working quickly. There is no reason for any of that to trigger a four-second delay before the user sees the results.

I can see two possible sources of delay:

- `Intent.createChooser()` is slow. That would be surprising, as it does not do any real work. For example, [here is the `createChooser()` implementation for Android 8.1](https://github.com/aosp-mirror/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-cts-8.1_r7/core/java/android/content/Intent.java#L979-L1013). Nothing in there should be slow.
- The system is slow in displaying the chooser activity. In other words, your `startActivity()` call happens quickly, but then the system is taking four seconds to display the result. There is nothing that you can do about that, other than perhaps try to take steps to clean up the test device (reboot? factory reset?).

Comment: I've exactly the same problem, if the user taps multi times in the share button multiple choosers appear to the user. I tried Intent Flags to avoid without success.
Do you know if it's possible to avoid multi instance of the `IntentChooser`?

Comment: @extmkv: I have never experienced this behavior, so I do not know of any solution. Sorry!

Comment: I have also seen the same issue in multiple devices